# vp8 rtp packetization data overwritten by srtp_protect

Tags: webrtc, rtp, vp8

I am using libsrtp for srtp encryption in a webrtc call.

After I prepare RTP packet, I call srtp_protect to encrypt it. It encrypts the data part and keeps RTP header as it is. This was working fine till now with audio only calls.

Now I am supporting VP8. As per RFC 7741 (RTP VP8 packetization), the RTP packet is like  RTP header + VP8 packetization data + Payload.

So when I feed this entire buffer to srtp_protect,it is encrypting the VP8 packetization portion and Payload. My understanding is that RTP header, VP8 packetization portion should not be encrypted. Only payload should be encrypted.

Is my understanding correct?

How can I use srtp_protect incase of RTP VP8 packetization?

Any hint highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I was worked on VoIP. I found in my code RTP packet prepared properly and it contains RTP header VP8 packetization data and VP8 actual payload. After that this whole packet given to SRTP library for encryption and this encrypted packet sent to other end.

At my end I also receive encrypted packet. I first decrypt packet using SRTP library after that I can extract rest of data like RTP header, vp8 packetization data and actual encoded vp8 payload.

Hope you get clarification on your doubt.

Comment: Pankaj Vavadiya your question on the chrome extension replace text could you give example for find and replace zip code with correct zip